# Keyboard Keys not functioning consistantly

Tags: keyboard

I have a HP Pavilion g7-2017us Notebook PC, I will be typing and all of the letters do not type when I press them. It is very sporadic and not any particular key.

Comment: Does it happen more often when you are typing very quickly? Does it make a beep sound when letters are missed? Has it always been this way or did it just start doing this all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0):

Open your Task Manager (WinKey + T)
when the keyboard issues arise, if your CPU is also spiking to high usage then your problem is latency caused by an overworked CPU.

Respond further if that didn't help.